# Site definition for multi-site in Sitecore habitat

Tags: helix, multisite, habitat

Currently we have a one Sitecore instance on Sitecore 8.1 with 9 sites hosted using habitat framework. The site definitions are mentioned as follows:

```
site name="Site1" loginPage="/home"  requireLogin="true" patch:before="site[@name='scheduler']"

site name="Site9" loginPage="/home"  requireLogin="true" patch:before="site[@name='scheduler']"
```

While opening a page item of site 1 or site 2 in the experience editor, the query string for sc_site is always pointing to site9. Example: `sc_lang=en&**sc_site=site9**.`

Is this an expected behavior? Or is there any issue in the `SiteDefinition.config`?

Comment: Does all the site has the same rootpath and startItem?

Comment: Can you please check this link. It seems that the patch referenced in this article has been incorporated into the Sitecore 8.1 https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/382913 Check the below setting in Sitecore.Config: <setting name="Preview.DefaultSite" value="website"/>

Comment: Hello Hishaam, the rootpath will site specific /sitecore/content/site1, /sitecore/content/site2 etc.  The startItem will be /Home for all the sites.

Comment: you can set host name for each site in the sitedefinition. login with hostname url to cm environment with which site you want see in Experience editor.

Comment: You are missing the hostname in you site config.

Comment: @PVM FYI, you said you have 9 sites hosted using habitat framework.  I hope you meant helix framework, and that you didn't use the habitat source to create your own sites on top of, since habitat should only be used as a reference and not a starter kit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `SiteDefinition.config` file each site should contain a `hostName` attribute. Sitecore will match the correct site based on the incoming url and matching `hostName`.

Check out the [SDN page for hostName](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/hostName.aspx) configuration for more information.